# how to end tests with jest and socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, jestjs

In my project I use `jest` as a test runner.
Testing the pure functions is easy,
but I find myself fighting the errors thrown from `jest`'s expects.

I want to test async code (based on messages) using `socket.io`.

```
  test('async', (done) => {
    const s = createConnection(config.port)

    s.on(WORLD, () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true)
        done()
    })
    s.emit(HELLO)
  })
```

Running this test works as expected, the socket client send a message,
then receive the response and expect something then `done`.
The problem is when the expect fails, since `jest` throw it as an error,
the `done` never get called, and I need to wrap it in `try-catch` block:

```
  test('async', (done) => {
    const s = createConnection(config.port)

    s.on(WORLD, () => {
      try {
        expect(false).toBe(true)
        done()
      } catch (e) {
        done(e)
      }
    })
    s.emit(HELLO)
  })
```

This way of writing tests (wrapping everything with `try-catch` blocks)
is very tedious, and I was wondering if there is a way of telling jest
to continue running after failing an `expect`.